# How to send discount coupon for those customers who didn't place any orders in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer-group, coupon-codes

A solution I think it is to create a new customers group from

```
Stores -> Customer Groups
```

and create a cart price rule to this group only.

When you create a new Group you have to select a tax class. But there is only one in list: "retail customer".

**How can I add a new tax class, that I have to select and that puts the customers automatically in this group based if the number of orders placed is 0 or not?**

Or any other solution for creating coupons for those who didn't place any orders

Comment: you mean new customer only able to get discount with coupon code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to check if a customer has made any order.

So in your case try to load all the customer that you have like this ;

```
You need to inject \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer class to get customer collection

<?php

    protected $_customers;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_customers = $customers;
        ...
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        //Get customer collection
        return $this->_customers->getCollection();
    }

    public function getCustomer($customerId)
    {
        //Get customer by customerID
        return $this->_customers->load($customerId);
    }

}
```

Now you can get customer collection or customer by customerID in phtml file

```
<?php

//Get customer collection
$collection = $this->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $customer) {
    echo $customer->getEmail(); // Get Customer Email
}


//Get customer by ID
$customerId = 1;
$customer = $this->getCustomer($customerId);
echo $customer->getEmail(); // Get customer Email

?>
```

and then check if they have any order

This will check the first order of the customer. If the customer dosen't have a "first order' this means that he/she didn't order anything yet.

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function getFirstOrder($emailId){
        $emailId = 'testtest@testtests.com';

        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',array('eq'=>$emailId))->getFirstItem();

        if($order->getCustomerEmail()){
            echo 'second time order';
        }
        else{
            echo 'first time order';
        }

    }
```

So you need to load all the customer and then make a foreach and check for each if they have first order or not. I hope this will help.